# How to create Django global settings with models?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm looking for solution in some trivial Django task.

**I need to create Global settings in Django admin.**

Not really sure how to implement model which migrate table in database with global settings and connect this settings with Django admin.

I'm using Django 2.0.6
Thank yo very much for any clues and tips.